# Sharing files between microservices built in Node, React and Python in a monorepo

Tags: microservices, monorepo, lerna

We have a monorepo that contains microservices/code in Node, React and Python. The directory structure looks like following:

[image: Directory Structure]

We are planning to create a `common` directory at the top-level to contain common files such as i18n files. The directory structure will look like following afterwards:

[image: Directory Structure with common]

What are the best practices to share common files between different microservices?

P.S. I came across [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) for this but the problem is that Lerna only supports JS projects. Do we have any other tools that support polyglot microservices in a monorepo?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Mariusz - Not yet.